# Angular: Declaring array of objects in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to declare an array of object in Typescript. However, I'm facing error retrieving the object. Below is my code. Image shows output of `this.attachments`.

```
info: Info[];

if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
  this.previewInfo(this.attachments);
}

previewInfo(infos) {
  this.info = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      var temp = new Info;
      temp = {
        id: i,
        url: e.target.result,
        message: ""
      }
      this.info.push(temp);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(infos[i]);
  }
}
```

The result I get contains an empty array in front which looks like this.

```
[]0: {id: 0, url: "test1", message: ""}
1: {id: 1, url: "test2", message: ""}
2: {id: 2, url: "test3", message: ""}
```

This causes undefined when I try to retrieve them using

```
this.info[0]
```

If I skip the second line which is `this.info=[]`, I'm getting an error which says

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Did I declare it wrongly? How can I retrieve info by index?

[image: Image shows output of <code>this.attachments</code>]

Comment: It's better if u shared more code, well there are some basic mistake, first, you are declaring info without `this`, but you are trying to access `info` with `this` in next line,  `this.info` will create new info object in your context which I believe is some event handler, now if you try to access this.info when you remove the second you will get an error because there is not any `info` on `this` context, read https://tylermcginnis.com/this-keyword-call-apply-bind-javascript/ & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @Harshkurra I can't declare info with `this` in typescript.

Comment: show where you  are calling previewInfo(infos)

Comment: @LuisRico updated as per request.

Comment: better that you share a MVCE stackblitz here

Comment: @AkberIqbal [stackblitz requested](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipyocr)

Comment: The issue is of asynchronous calls; when your loop finishes and these 2 lines are executed... by that time the `reader.onload` hadn't finished and therefore `this.info.push(temp);` didn't run and you see a blank in your console 

    console.log(this.info);
    console.log(this.info[0]); //this is what i need

Comment: @AkberIqbal got it working. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is of asynchronous calls;

When your loop finishes and these 2 lines are executed... by that time the `reader.onload` hadn't finished and therefore `this.info.push(temp);` didn't run and you see a blank in your console when you run these 2 lines below:

```
console.log(this.info);
console.log(this.info[0]); //this is what i need
```

What we need to do is to let the loop finish, and in the very last iteration (where `i == infos.length - 1`) of the loop... we print the values on the console and get the correct result;

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  //Variable declaration
  attachments = [];
  info = [];

  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.attachments = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < event.target.files.length; index++) {
      var file = event.target.files[index];
      this.attachments.push(file);
    }
    if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
      this.previewInfo(this.attachments);
      console.log('caller', this.attachments);
    }
  }

  previewInfo(infos) {
    this.info = [];
    if (infos) {
      for (let i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          let temp = {
            id: i,
            url: e.target.result,
            message: "",
          }
          //console.log(temp);
          if (i == infos.length - 1) {
            this.pusher(temp, true);
          } else {
            this.pusher(temp, false);
          }
          //this.info.push(temp, function(){ console.log('pushed'); } );
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(infos[i]);
      }
      console.log('empty: ', this.info);
      console.log('empty: ', this.info[0]); //this is what i need
    }
  }

  pusher(tempFile, lastFile) {
    this.info.push(tempFile);
    if (lastFile == true) {
      console.log('Correct Filled: ', this.info.length);
      console.log('Correct Filled: ', this.info[0]); //this is what i need
    }
  }

}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6vs4d)

Answer (score 1):

Akber Iqbal's answer works, but their solution does not guarantee that the files are in the same order as the `attachments` array, so

here is a solution, if there is an importance of that the `info` items are in the same order as the files in the `attachments` array. You are looking for the first item, so maybe it is important. We can use Promises and `async/await`:

```ts
async onFileSelected(event) {
  this.attachments = [];
  this.info = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < event.target.files.length; index++) {
    let file = event.target.files[index];
    this.attachments.push(file);
  }

  if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
      try {
        // wait that the file has been processed before moving on to next file
        let temp = await this.readFile(this.attachments[i], i);
        this.info.push(temp)

        if (this.attachments.length === this.info.length) {
          // here we have the first item after all files has been completed
          console.log(this.info[0])
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And processing the file from the `for`-loop here, by passing the file and the index and returning the temp file:

```ts
readFile(file, i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      let temp = {
        id: i,
        url: e.target.result,
        message: file.name, // for testing I put the file name as message
      }
      resolve(temp);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
}
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pthuaj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**